# Jquery AJAX: Refresh <article>'s content on success?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php page with this structure:

```
body{ article { form { table } } }
```

I want the  tag to refresh it's content when the form is submitted since i need to add new data to the form table that has been added to the database.
I am writing the following jquery code inside `success` of AJAX.

```
$("article").load("add.php article");
```

i.e. i want to refresh same page with new content without actual refresh..
It works fine except that it breaks away my CSS. 
Is there any way that i can remove `<article>` tag from my page on success and then create a new `<article>`element on the page?

Comment: It should not break your css, are you sure your html structure isn't changed in any way?

Comment: @red-x : yea..i firebugged it..it adds a new <article> inside previous <article>. How do i prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try(not tested):

```
$("article").load("add.php article > *");
```

Instead of getting the article it gets the content of the article.